# Air India delayed by 5 hours

Tags: air-travel, delays, compensation, air-india

Can you please let me know whether I can claim anything as my flight got delayed by 5 hours in New Delhi by Air India. My transit supposed to be 5 hours and top of this they announced that my flight from New Delhi to London delayed by 5 hours. So, I have to wait 10 hours in total. Is there anything that I can do to claim for that delay 5 hours by Air India?

Comment: What was the exact itinerary that was delayed?

Comment: do you have travel insurance cover? if yes, then you can claim with the insurance company. The airline is also supposed to compensate you like putting you in another flight or one night stay in hotel.